# Declaration is on valid at file scope (UI color extension)

Tags: xcode, swift3, uicolor, swift-extensions

Okay so I have an error with my extension, which whenever I add a line or space it up it creates more errors with the UIColor. I can use the Clean function to get it back down to these two errors. My extension is not in {} and I think I have all my blocks closed, but maybe not. It was working fine before I made 'FIRAuth Create User' function if that has anything to do with it. [Issue Navigator + the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TE0k.png)

```
extension UIColor{

    convenience init (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a previous block perhaps missing a close curly brace? If a preceding class or extension is still open, then this extension isn't at file scope – it's one level deeper, which is invalid. I'd double-check that all of your preceding scopes are closed as you expect.

Comment: Is there a quick way to do that besides looking through your code slowly... like way you can highlight and closing Curly and it will highlight the corresponding open Curly?

Comment: I'd select everything in the file and hit Control+I, which will automatically reindent your code. Then you can glance through and see the point where everything suddenly shifts an extra tab to the right.

Comment: In addition, Xcode allows you to expand & collapse scopes using the left gutter of the source editor. You can also highlight the contents of a pair of braces by double-clicking on either brace.